# Create excel macro to compare en select data

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros so i dont know how to write one,  but i think i have to use one to do what want on excel

I have two sheets (Datachart and Datapivottabel) 
the datachart sheet contains  (in column C startting at row5) 189 names (end at row 193)
the Datapivottabel sheet contains a pivottabel(updatebale) in this pivot table i have some names  of  198 names (not all of them the number depends  from the filter  of the pivottabel) on the column A on column B i have  values
 i want to display in Datachart sheet column E  the values that  are compared from  Datapivotabel sheet

For example

**Datachart sheet:**

```
col C               |col E (the values i want)
Ukraine             |0 (because there  is no match)
United Arab Emirates|50
United Kingdom      |180
United States       |30
Uruguay             |11
Uzbekistan          |0 (because there is no match)
```

**Datapivottabel sheet:**

```
col A               |col B
United Arab Emirates|50
United Kingdom      |180
United States       |30
Uruguay             |11
```

i hope u understand the situation
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell E5 on the "Datachart" sheet and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Datapivottabel!B:B,MATCH(C5,Datapivottabel!A:A,0)),0)
```